# VS does not allow me to invoke my extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

For any reason, VS allows me to use the long writing of my extension method invocation. But compiler rejects the shorter form:

public static  class OperationExtender {

```
public static void MyMethod(Operation ope, int value) {
  ...
}
```

}

I can invoke it this way:

```
OperationExtender.MyMethod(anOperation, 0);
```

But if I type:

```
anOperation.OperationExtender(0);
```

VS generates this usual comilation error:

```
 'OperationExtender.MyMethod(Operation, int)' 
 does not contain a definition for
'MyMethod' and no extension method 'MyMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'Operation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If the first writing is accepted, I suppose it cannot be a usung/NS/assembly issue....

Comment: You're missing `this` before the `Operation ope` parameter, so it's not an extension method.

Comment: is your extension method are in same namespace?

Comment: Obviously I was missing this, thx CodeCaster :)

Comment: Did you do any googling before asking it here?  You would have found the answer very quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's not an extension method.  You forgot the `this` keyword on the first parameter (the type being "extended"):

```
public static void MyMethod(this Operation ope, int value) {
    //...
}
```